# how to hide 'measure' part of a cross tab in BIRT report?

Tags: birt

I want to aggregate the measure on a row and show only the aggregated part, keeping the measure part hidden. I tried 'visibility - Hide Elements' option for this, but that just makes the measure's values hidden, still it leaves the blank rows behind in the result (PDF/ Excel/ any other format). Could anyone help out here how to get rid of the blank rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of what it is that you are trying to avoid? Thanks.